# Connecting ipega 9037 Bluetooth gamepad via USB-OTG to smartphone

Tags: usb-on-the-go, game-controllers

I have a problem with my device while pairing my ipega 9037 Bluetooth gamepad controller. The joysticks are working and also the D-pad, but I have thought that can I use this controller over USB OTG.

Does it damage the smartphone battery?

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking it trough the cable and not Bluetooth, it won't drain much more battery than pressing the volume buttons.

In other words, nothing you'll ever notice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the PS4 controller. When I use OTG, my phone battery goes down.

I open up my controller and disconnect the battery. Then when I connect via OTG, it doesn't charge the controller. No more, it's perfect.